# Dropdown is not keeping the value selected

Tags: flutter

I am working on a dropdown and I have the values in a variable, but I can't get the selected value to be shown, instead is always a static value on.

So far I did this:

```
class DropDownWidget extends State {
  String dropdownValue = 'Activities';
  String holder = '';

  List<String> postType = ['Activities', 'Sell/buy', 'New Friends', 'City Recommendations', 'Post'];

  void getDropDownItem() {
    setState(() {
      holder = dropdownValue;
    });
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Container(
      height: 100,
      decoration: BoxDecoration(
        image: DecorationImage(
          image: AssetImage('assets/img/blue.png'),
          fit: BoxFit.cover,
        ),
      ),
      child: Row(
        mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceAround,
        children: [
      
                      Container(
           
            
            child: DropdownButton<String>(
              value: dropdownValue,
              icon: Icon(
                Icons.keyboard_arrow_down_outlined,
                color: TheBaseColors.lightRed,
              ),
              iconSize: 30,
              elevation: 16,
              style: TextStyle(color: TheBaseColors.lightRed, fontSize: 18),
              onChanged: (String data) {
                setState(() {
                  dropdownValue = data;
                });
                switch (data) {
                  case 'Activities':
                    Navigator.push(
                      context,
                      MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => CreateActivity()),
                    );
                    break;
                  case 'Sell/buy':
                    Navigator.push(
                      context,
                    
                }
              },
              items: postType.map<DropdownMenuItem<String>>((String value) {
                return DropdownMenuItem<String>(
                  value: value,
                  child: Text(value),
                );
              }).toList(),
            ),
          ),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

I have saved the dropdow value in a variable and then set it in the SetState, but how to show the selected item each time?

Answer (score -1):

Try This

```
String dropdownValue = 'Activities';
DropdownButton<String>(
    value: dropdownValue,
    icon: const Icon(Icons.arrow_downward),
    iconSize: 24,
    elevation: 16,
    style: const TextStyle(color: Colors.deepPurple),
    underline: Container(
      height: 2,
      color: Colors.deepPurpleAccent,
    ),
    onChanged: (String? newValue) {
      setState(() {
        dropdownValue = newValue!;
      });
    },
    items: <String>['Activities', 'Sell/buy', 'New Friends', 'City Recommendations', 'Post']
        .map<DropdownMenuItem<String>>((String value) {
      return DropdownMenuItem<String>(
        value: value,
        child: Text(value),
      );
    }).toList(),
  ),
```